# Join tables in schema.graphql

Tags: graphql, amazon-dynamodb

I'm on aws amplify DynamoDB.

I have two tables:

```
type User @model @auth(rules: [{allow: public}]) {
    id: ID!
    name: String
}
```

and

```
type MyUsers @model @auth(rules: [{allow: public}]) {
        id: ID!
        owner: ID!
        user: ID       
}
```

When I query MyUsers with a "owner" filter, I want to retrieve each associated User.

I tried

```
type User @model @auth(rules: [{allow: public}]) {
    id: ID!
    name: String
    myUsers: MyUsers @belongsTo(fields: ["id"])
}
```

and

```
type MyUsers @model @auth(rules: [{allow: public}]) {
        id: ID!
        owner: ID!
        userID: ID
        user: User @hasOne(fields: ["userID"])       
}
```

But it doesnt return Users

How can I get a listMyUsers that return the User content ?